# NopCommerce Netsparker security scan, cookie not marked as secure

Tags: security, cookies, nopcommerce

NopCommerce 3.40 && Netsparker 3.5.11.0 (scanner)

How do I mark this cookie as Secure?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the application settings.
Considering NopCommerce is an ASP.NET application, there are External References in the Netsparker Vulnerability Details section which guides you about how to set cookies as Secure.